# Moving pallet between racks Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Is it possible to move pallet between two different racks directly, without adding intermediate point node? For example I have two racks one at the receiving dock and one a the storage, after unloading all pallets to Receiving rack I need to send it to storage rack. So I understand I need to add two blocks Rack Pick and Rack store. Is it possible to combine those two?

Answer (score 0):

You can always combine any number of blocks and make your own composite block. Select them, right-click and choose "create flowchart block".

[This tutorial](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_Material%2Ftutorial%2FPhase_7.html&cp=1_1_7) (phase 7) shows you how to do it and how to make it as flexible/reusable as you want.

Comment: No worries. But please mark the answer as "useful" (up-arrow next to it) so others can find the answer faster in the future. Welcome to SOF :-)